# what are Squamariaceae and Marcgravia processes which consume lot of cpu on macOS Mojave

Tags: osx, malware

I rencently found that two processes called Squamariaceae and Marcgravia where launched every now and then on my laptop and I wonder about their purposes.

Indeed, I had never seen them before and they tend to diminish very rapidely my battery.

[image: screenshot of processes and their activity]

Here are my two questions :

- Does anyone know about these programs ? Are they dangegerous ?
- Is there a easy/safe way to kill a program (owned by root) by its name whenever it is started via a bash script ?

Comment: This does not appear to be a Unix question. (yes I know that MacOS is built on Unix).

Comment: I agree for the first part of the question, but I don't know where else to ask it.
Howver, the second part of the question is more about Unix system right ?